# jquery load content in modal div, it shows content only at the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a page made with jquery/bootstrap, with the following code that when clicked it will open a modal:

```
<a class="projects" data-id="test.html" 
   href="#modal" data-modal-target="#modal" data-modal-effect="fadein">
   LOAD CONTENT
</a>
```

more down in the page I have the modal `div`:

```
<div id="modal" style="display: none;">
  <h4>Modal title</h4>
  <p>dummy description</p>
  <div id="dinamiccontent">X</div>
</div>
```

then I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".projects").click(function(){
       var lurl = String($(this).data('id'));
       $("#dinamiccontent").load(lurl);
   });
});            
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click on the link the modal opens correctly and shows `X` at the `dinamiccontent` `div` when it should show the content of `test.html`, but if I click a second time the same link, it opens the modal with showing correctly the `test.html` content!

I'm spending hours on reading docs, answers and sites, and made many changes to the code but I can't come up with a solution.

I would like to load the modal with the content of `test.html` preloaded in the `dinamiccontent` `div` at the first click on the above link. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to get a working version of this using both Bootstrap `3.3.7` and `4.0.0-alpha.6`

I did restructure your modal to follow the Bootstrap guidelines, it needs more than just an `id="modal"`. I also changed your attributes in the link that toggles the modal. Try each one of these changes individually to see if they can fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="projects" href="" data-id="test.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"> <!-- Note the 'data-toggle' and 'data-target' -->
     LOAD CONTENT
  </a>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".projects").click(function() {
        var lurl = String($(this).data('id'));
        $(".modal-body").load(lurl);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a link to check it out: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/chatter-polish